# double hyphen in execvp() python

Tags: python, execvp

There're some strange behaviors, why does not double hyphen(--) work for execvp() in python:

```
import os

os.execvp('./pro', ['--resume', 'a', 'b'])

# ./pro looks like this
##!/usr/bin/python

#import sys

#if len(sys.argv) >=3:
#    for i in sys.argv:
#        print i # expects './pro\n --resume\n a\n b\n', got './pro\n a\n b\n'
```

Comment: Have you tried using `subprocess` instead of `os.execvp`? It's generally easier to work with.

Comment: That's not what goes in the first slot of that array...

Answer (score 2):

Your first argument is being overlaid by the script name. Probably what you intended was this:

```
os.execvp('./pro', ['./pro', '--resume', 'a', 'b'])
```

The first argument in the argument vector given to `execvp` is by convention the name of the program itself. When using the `'#!'` mechanism to invoke the python interpreter, this convention is upgraded to a fact.

What I mean is that if `./pro` was a binary (as from a C program, for example), you would see `'--resume'` as argument 0, but the process of invoking the interpreter is overwriting that argument here. But I suspect you actually meant to pass `'--resume'` as an argument to your sub-program.